# Can we ever have limsup$(x_n)= - \infty $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence in $(-\infty, \infty]$.

Could we define the sequence $(x_n)$ so that limsup$(x_n) = -\infty$?

My intuitive thought is no, but I’m not 100% sure.

Comment: What is $\limsup_{n\to\infty} (-n)$?

Comment: Of course. Take $x_n = -n$.

Comment: Of course... every unbounded below sequence will have a subsuequnce that diverges to $-\infty$, And thus will have $\lim\sup\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=-\infty$ (That’s in the proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem for unbounded sequences).

Answer (score 2):

Consider $(x_{n})$ defined by $x_{n} = -n$. Then
$$ \limsup_{n \to \infty} x_{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sup_{m \geq n} \ (-m) \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \ ( -n ) = -\infty. $$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that when a sequence $a_n$ has limit $L\in \mathbb{\bar R}$ the following holds

$$\lim a_n=\liminf a_n=\limsup a_n=L$$

therefore for any $a_n \to -\infty$ we have $\limsup a_n=-\infty$.